# How do I make a DataGrid scale the contents to any resolution?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to get my DataGrid to scale the Row Height, Column Width with the Window Size so that it can scale to any resolution. This sort of works but since 
I have the datagrid in a viewbox not all rows are showing and there isn't a horizontal scroll available. See Image.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TB1" Grid.Row="0" Text="League Name"/>
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="a" Binding="{Binding a}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="b"  Binding="{Binding b}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c"  Binding="{Binding c}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="d"  Binding="{Binding d}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="e"  Binding="{Binding e}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="f"  Binding="{Binding f}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="g"  Binding="{Binding g}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="h"  Binding="{Binding h}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Border Grid.Row="2">
        <Image Source="Resources/Logo.png" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Either ditch the parent Grid or make Height="*" of it's Row

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the Viewbox and set your DataGrid's Vertical and Horizontal alignments to 'Stretch'. You should also set your RowDefinition to "*" or just get rid of it all together (You don't need it since it is your only row).

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but by getting rid of the Viewbox the content doesnt resize anymore.